# if find ext then cp parent dir else echo not found

Tags: script

So far I have come up with this.

```
if ls -1 ~/Downloads/*.mkv >/dev/null 2>&1
then
        echo 1
else
        echo 0
fi
```

But what I would like to do is to then copy the parent dir of the found file to another location.

I have a feeling that I should just use the find command.

Comment: Can you please describe what you really need to accomplish? If a folder contains a `.mkv` you want to copy the folder somewhere else?

Comment: @slhck Yes, that is what I would like to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fede.evol's answer fails if paths contain whitespace. The output of `find` or `ls` [shouldn't be used in a command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

The proper way to deal with all filenames (except for paths with newlines) would be:

```
find /somewhere -name "*.mkv" -exec dirname {} \; | uniq | \
while IFS= read -r dir; do echo cp -- "$dir" /other/; done
```

This way, each folder from `/somewhere` is copied to `/other/`. Note that the trailing slash is mandatory, because otherwise the target would always be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Use `dirname FILE` to get the directory name of a given file. So for example:

```
find DIRECTORY -name "*.mkv" -exec dirname {} \;
```

Will give you all the directories with an MKV under DIRECTORY. Then you can pass them through `uniq` not to get doubles and then in case copy.

For example

```
cp -a `find DIRECTORY -name "*.mkv" -exec dirname {} \; | uniq` DESTDIR
```

Comment: Your last command will fail if the directory path contains spaces. You should not use command substitution on `find` or `ls` output.